# SQL Query to select only if there are a certain number of entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2008 R2

This is going to be hard to explain, but I don't feel comfortable giving actual details since this is a project for my employer.  To put a scenario together:  our database keeps track of wheels, their specs, and when they're put onto cars.  I need to pull the records for every wheel that's attached to a car that has all its wheels.  There's a field in my `Cars` table that tells me what type of car the entry is, an entry in my `CarTypes` table that tells me how many wheels each type of car has, and an entry in my `WheelPositions` table for each possible location on a car that the wheel could be placed.

I also need to produce a second, similar query to return a list of cars with wheels missing.

Currently, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  Cars.ID AS [CarID]
  ,CarTypes.Name AS [CarType]
  ,Wheels.ID AS [WheelID]
  ,WheelPositions.[Index] AS [PosIndex]
FROM
  Cars
  LEFT JOIN CarTypes ON Cars.Type = CarTypes.Name
  LEFT JOIN Wheels ON Cars.ID = Wheels.CarID
  LEFT JOIN WheelPositions ON Wheels.Position = WheelPositions.Value
    AND Wheels.Shop = WheelPositions.Shop
WHERE
  Cars.Visible = 'True'
```

This gives me a list of all the wheels that are attached to cars, but I don't know how to modify it to filter out cars that are missing a wheel or to include vacant positions on an incomplete car.

Just to be clear, I'm describing two separate queries, and am looking for help with either.

Answer (score 0):

`CarTypes` has a field with the number of wheels.  You can use this in an aggregation:

```
SELECT Cars.ID AS [CarID], CarTypes.Name AS [CarType]
FROM Cars LEFT JOIN
     CarTypes
     ON Cars.Type = CarTypes.Name LEFT JOIN
     Wheels
     ON Cars.ID = Wheels.CarID LEFT JOIN
     WheelPositions
     ON Wheels.Position = WheelPositions.Value AND Wheels.Shop = WheelPositions.Shop
WHERE Cars.Visible = 'True'
GROUP BY Cars.ID, CarTypes.Name, CarTypes.NumWheels
HAVING count(WheelPositions.Value) = CarTypes.NumWheels;
```

I'm not quite sure how to tell that a wheel is missing.  This is assuming that the field `WheelPositions.Value` is NULL.